# ClassName of window hwnd is modifying once in a while

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have an application in win32 that needs to find a certain window with FindWindow function. I noticed that classname of the window can change on the same computer. Can i know classname of the window beforehand or calculate somehow myself, so that my application always "finds" that specific window that i need to find.

Comment: Ask the vendor of the app. We don't know what the app is. We don't have its code.

Comment: I thought it might be informative. Not only to me..don't get the downvotes. I noticed that classname changes pretty frequently on the same window on the same computer. It looked weird to me.

Comment: As I said, the author of the app knows the answer. Nobody here does. You might be wise to run through the early chapters of Petzold to gain a clearer understanding of how windows are created. Then you'd be better placed.

Comment: I believe you want the `ITimeMachine` interface. It lets your program see into the future.

Answer (score 2):

The class name is arbitrarily chosen by the author of a window class. The only requirements are, that it is no more than 256 characters, and unique. There is no algorithm involved in creating a class name, and it cannot be calculated. It is set in a call to [RegisterClassEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587.aspx) (see the *lpszClassName* member of the [WNDCLASSEX structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577.aspx)).

Comment: Yes thanks of course i know  about the RegisterClassEx. :)

Comment: If you already know all of this, then I wonder what you are really asking. Have we understood the question correctly?